# next start with --keepAliveTimeout

Tags: next.js

I was following the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli and I have my script defined as

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start --keepAliveTimeout 70000",
```

but I am getting error

```
Unknown or unexpected option: --keepAliveTimeout
```

I want to include this option as I am experiencing 503 errors on my pod deployed to k8s cluster.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to that page, it looks like the option to `start` should actually be:

```
npx next start --keepAliveTimeout 70000
```

I'm no expert here, but I think what is happening (without using `npx`) is that the arguments are not being *consumed* by the correct software. If so, this might also be a way to fix that:

```
next start -- --keepAliveTimeout 70000"
```

Often, programs will use `--` to separate arguments for the called script/program (`next`, in your case), and arguments to be passed to the software the program itself will call internally.

Update:

I've looked through the next source code, and I can't see why it's failing with what you were originally using. Perhaps the behavior of `next` has changed recently, in which case you might consider upgrading.